# Python: Problema com números aleatórios dentro de while

Tags: python, while, random

Gostaria de saber com resolver um pequeno problema que estou enfrentando nesse e outros códigos.

Ao testar o exemplo perceberá que ele vai usar o mesmo `atk` sempre, ou seja se ele escolher o `atk 1`, ele vai ficar com esse `atk` até o final do código.

Gostaria que a cada repetição ele escolhesse uma variável diferente, em vez de escolher uma aleatoriamente e ficar em todas as repetições, eu queria que a cada repetição ele escolhesse uma outra variável.

```
from time import sleep
import random
#------------------jogador------------------#
Hp_Jogador   = 120
Atk_Jogador  = 20
Atk_Jogador1 = 30
Atk_Jogador2 = 40
#------------------inimigo------------------#
Hp_Inimigo   = 120
Atk_Inimigo  = 20
Atk_Inimigo1 = 30
Atk_Inimigo2 = 40
list = [Atk_Inimigo, Atk_Inimigo1, Atk_Inimigo2 ]
atki = random.choice(list)
r = 0
print('Você encontrou um inimigo!')
sleep(1)
print(f'Inimigo HP:120')
print('Jogador HP: 120')
while Hp_Inimigo > 0 or Hp_Jogador < 0:
    r += 1
    sleep(1)
    print(f'-=-round {r}-=- ')
    print()
    sleep(2)
    print('[1] Bola de fogo: 20')
    print('[2] Estaca de gelo: 30')
    print('[3] Elétro Shock: 40')
    print()
    #-------------------jogador------------------#
    a = int(input('Escolha seu ataque:'))

    if a == 1:
        Hp_Inimigo = Hp_Inimigo - Atk_Jogador
    if a == 2:
        Hp_Inimigo = Hp_Inimigo - Atk_Jogador1
    if a == 3:
        Hp_Inimigo = Hp_Inimigo - Atk_Jogador2
    print()
    print(f'HP Inimigo: {Hp_Inimigo}')

#-------------------inimigo------------------#
    Hp_Jogador = Hp_Jogador - atki
    print(f'Hp_Jogador: {Hp_Jogador}')
    if Hp_Inimigo <= 0:
        print("Você venceu")
        break
    elif Hp_Jogador <= 0:
        print('Você perdeu')
        break
```

Comment: Joga isso: `atki = random.choice(list)` para dentro do while.

Comment: Pegue essa linha `atki = random.choice(list)` e insira no início do loop `while Hp_Inimigo > 0 or Hp_Jogador < 0:` veja se é isso que procura?

Answer (score -1):

Não consegui entender muito bem o seu código, mas aparentemente o problema está no fato de você estar usando uma variável para gerar um número aleatório, quando na verdade, deveria estar gerando um número aleatório para cada `ATK_Jogador`. Armazenar uma função random em uma variável faz com que quando o programa leia seu código, faça com que a variável tenha o valor aleatório estático e o mesmo não mudará toda vez que você chamar pela variável. Para resolver isso em seu código substitua:

```
Atk_Jogador(n)
```

por

```
random.choice(sua_lista)
```